# Fitting Lorentzian function

Tags: fitting

I'm trying to fit a Lorentzian function to my data, but i can't find the best fit.
The model used is

```
ws = 4.3256;
eps1 = (t - ws)/(a);

model1 = 1 - 1 /(1 + eps1^2)

result = NonlinearModelFit[data, model1, {a}, t, MaxIterations -> 500, Method -> {NMinimize}]
dataplot = ListPlot[data];

fitplot = Plot[result[x], {x, 4.0, 5.0}, PlotStyle -> Red, PlotRange -> All];

Show[dataplot, fitplot]
```

which gives

[image: plot]

I added my data here:

```
data={{4.0036,0.6376},{4.0046,0.6361},{4.0056,0.6346},{4.0066,0.6331},{4.0076,0.6316},{4.0086,0.6301},{4.0096,0.6286},{4.0106,0.6271},{4.0116,0.6256},{4.0126,0.624},{4.0136,0.6225},{4.0146,0.621},{4.0156,0.6194},{4.0166,0.6179},{4.0176,0.6163},{4.0186,0.6148},{4.0196,0.6132},{4.0206,0.6116},{4.0216,0.61},{4.0226,0.6084},{4.0236,0.6068},{4.0246,0.6052},{4.0256,0.6036},{4.0266,0.602},{4.0276,0.6004},{4.0286,0.5988},{4.0296,0.5971},{4.0306,0.5955},{4.0316,0.5939},{4.0326,0.5922},{4.0336,0.5906},{4.0346,0.5889},{4.0356,0.5872},{4.0366,0.5855},{4.0376,0.5839},{4.0386,0.5822},{4.0396,0.5805},{4.0406,0.5788},{4.0416,0.577},{4.0426,0.5753},{4.0436,0.5736},{4.0446,0.5719},{4.0456,0.5701},{4.0466,0.5684},{4.0476,0.5666},{4.0486,0.5649},{4.0496,0.5631},{4.0506,0.5613},{4.0516,0.5596},{4.0526,0.5578},{4.0536,0.556},{4.0546,0.5542},{4.0556,0.5524},{4.0566,0.5506},{4.0576,0.5487},{4.0586,0.5469},{4.0596,0.5451},{4.0606,0.5432},{4.0616,0.5414},{4.0626,0.5395},{4.0636,0.5377},{4.0646,0.5358},{4.0656,0.5339},{4.0666,0.532},{4.0676,0.5301},{4.0686,0.5282},{4.0696,0.5263},{4.0706,0.5244},{4.0716,0.5225},{4.0726,0.5206},{4.0736,0.5186},{4.0746,0.5167},{4.0756,0.5148},{4.0766,0.5128},{4.0776,0.5108},{4.0786,0.5089},{4.0796,0.5069},{4.0806,0.5049},{4.0816,0.5029},{4.0826,0.5009},{4.0836,0.4989},{4.0846,0.4969},{4.0856,0.4949},{4.0866,0.4928},{4.0876,0.4908},{4.0886,0.4888},{4.0896,0.4867},{4.0906,0.4847},{4.0916,0.4826},{4.0926,0.4805},{4.0936,0.4785},{4.0946,0.4764},{4.0956,0.4743},{4.0966,0.4722},{4.0976,0.4701},{4.0986,0.468},{4.0996,0.4658},{4.1006,0.4637},{4.1016,0.4616},{4.1026,0.4594},{4.1036,0.4573},{4.1046,0.4551},{4.1056,0.453},{4.1066,0.4508},{4.1076,0.4486},{4.1086,0.4464},{4.1096,0.4442},{4.1106,0.442},{4.1116,0.4398},{4.1126,0.4376},{4.1136,0.4354},{4.1146,0.4332},{4.1156,0.4309},{4.1166,0.4287},{4.1176,0.4264},{4.1186,0.4242},{4.1196,0.4219},{4.1206,0.4197},{4.1216,0.4174},{4.1226,0.4151},{4.1236,0.4128},{4.1246,0.4105},{4.1256,0.4082},{4.1266,0.4059},{4.1276,0.4036},{4.1286,0.4013},{4.1296,0.3989},{4.1306,0.3966},{4.1316,0.3943},{4.1326,0.3919},{4.1336,0.3896},{4.1346,0.3872},{4.1356,0.3848},{4.1366,0.3824},{4.1376,0.3801},{4.1386,0.3777},{4.1396,0.3753},{4.1406,0.3729},{4.1416,0.3705},{4.1426,0.3681},{4.1436,0.3657},{4.1446,0.3632},{4.1456,0.3608},{4.1466,0.3584},{4.1476,0.3559},{4.1486,0.3535},{4.1496,0.351},{4.1506,0.3486},{4.1516,0.3461},{4.1526,0.3436},{4.1536,0.3412},{4.1546,0.3387},{4.1556,0.3362},{4.1566,0.3337},{4.1576,0.3312},{4.1586,0.3287},{4.1596,0.3262},{4.1606,0.3237},{4.1616,0.3212},{4.1626,0.3187},{4.1636,0.3162},{4.1646,0.3137},{4.1656,0.3111},{4.1666,0.3086},{4.1676,0.3061},{4.1686,0.3035},{4.1696,0.301},{4.1706,0.2984},{4.1716,0.2959},{4.1726,0.2933},{4.1736,0.2908},{4.1746,0.2882},{4.1756,0.2856},{4.1766,0.2831},{4.1776,0.2805},{4.1786,0.2779},{4.1796,0.2753},{4.1806,0.2728},{4.1816,0.2702},{4.1826,0.2676},{4.1836,0.265},{4.1846,0.2624},{4.1856,0.2598},{4.1866,0.2573},{4.1876,0.2547},{4.1886,0.2521},{4.1896,0.2495},{4.1906,0.2469},{4.1916,0.2443},{4.1926,0.2417},{4.1936,0.2391},{4.1946,0.2365},{4.1956,0.2339},{4.1966,0.2313},{4.1976,0.2287},{4.1986,0.2261},{4.1996,0.2235},{4.2006,0.2209},{4.2016,0.2183},{4.2026,0.2157},{4.2036,0.2131},{4.2046,0.2106},{4.2056,0.208},{4.2066,0.2054},{4.2076,0.2028},{4.2086,0.2002},{4.2096,0.1976},{4.2106,0.1951},{4.2116,0.1925},{4.2126,0.1899},{4.2136,0.1874},{4.2146,0.1848},{4.2156,0.1823},{4.2166,0.1797},{4.2176,0.1772},{4.2186,0.1746},{4.2196,0.1721},{4.2206,0.1696},{4.2216,0.167},{4.2226,0.1645},{4.2236,0.162},{4.2246,0.1595},{4.2256,0.157},{4.2266,0.1545},{4.2276,0.152},{4.2286,0.1495},{4.2296,0.1471},{4.2306,0.1446},{4.2316,0.1421},{4.2326,0.1397},{4.2336,0.1373},{4.2346,0.1348},{4.2356,0.1324},{4.2366,0.13},{4.2376,0.1276},{4.2386,0.1252},{4.2396,0.1229},{4.2406,0.1205},{4.2416,0.1181},{4.2426,0.1158},{4.2436,0.1135},{4.2446,0.1112},{4.2456,0.1089},{4.2466,0.1066},{4.2476,0.1043},{4.2486,0.102},{4.2496,0.0998},{4.2506,0.0976},{4.2516,0.0953},{4.2526,0.0931},{4.2536,0.091},{4.2546,0.0888},{4.2556,0.0866},{4.2566,0.0845},{4.2576,0.0824},{4.2586,0.0803},{4.2596,0.0782},{4.2606,0.0761},{4.2616,0.0741},{4.2626,0.0721},{4.2636,0.0701},{4.2646,0.0681},{4.2656,0.0661},{4.2666,0.0641},{4.2676,0.0622},{4.2686,0.0603},{4.2696,0.0584},{4.2706,0.0566},{4.2716,0.0547},{4.2726,0.0529},{4.2736,0.0511},{4.2746,0.0494},{4.2756,0.0476},{4.2766,0.0459},{4.2776,0.0442},{4.2786,0.0425},{4.2796,0.0409},{4.2806,0.0393},{4.2816,0.0377},{4.2826,0.0361},{4.2836,0.0346},{4.2846,0.0331},{4.2856,0.0316},{4.2866,0.0302},{4.2876,0.0288},{4.2886,0.0274},{4.2896,0.026},{4.2906,0.0247},{4.2916,0.0234},{4.2926,0.0221},{4.2936,0.0209},{4.2946,0.0197},{4.2956,0.0185},{4.2966,0.0173},{4.2976,0.0162},{4.2986,0.0152},{4.2996,0.0141},{4.3006,0.0131},{4.3016,0.0121},{4.3026,0.0112},{4.3036,0.0103},{4.3046,0.0094248},{4.3056,0.0085931},{4.3066,0.0077976},{4.3076,0.0070388},{4.3086,0.0063168},{4.3096,0.0056322},{4.3106,0.0049852},{4.3116,0.0043761},{4.3126,0.0038053},{4.3136,0.0032731},{4.3146,0.0027798},{4.3156,0.0023257},{4.3166,0.0019112},{4.3176,0.0015365},{4.3186,0.0012019},{4.3196,0.00090778},{4.3206,0.00065435},{4.3216,0.0004419},{4.3226,0.00027071},{4.3236,0.00014103},{4.3246,0.000053129},{4.3256,7.2547*10^-6},{4.3266,3.6508*10^-6},{4.3276,0.000042554},{4.3286,0.00012419},{4.3296,0.00024879},{4.3306,0.00041656},{4.3316,0.0006277},{4.3326,0.00088242},{4.3336,0.0011809},{4.3346,0.0015233},{4.3356,0.0019099},{4.3366,0.0023407},{4.3376,0.002816},{4.3386,0.0033359},{4.3396,0.0039005},{4.3406,0.00451},{4.3416,0.0051644},{4.3426,0.005864},{4.3436,0.0066087},{4.3446,0.0073987},{4.3456,0.0082341},{4.3466,0.009115},{4.3476,0.01},{4.3486,0.011},{4.3496,0.012},{4.3506,0.0131},{4.3516,0.0142},{4.3526,0.0154},{4.3536,0.0166},{4.3546,0.0178},{4.3556,0.0191},{4.3566,0.0204},{4.3576,0.0218},{4.3586,0.0232},{4.3596,0.0247},{4.3606,0.0262},{4.3616,0.0278},{4.3626,0.0294},{4.3636,0.0311},{4.3646,0.0328},{4.3656,0.0345},{4.3666,0.0363},{4.3676,0.0381},{4.3686,0.04},{4.3696,0.0419},{4.3706,0.0439},{4.3716,0.0459},{4.3726,0.048},{4.3736,0.0501},{4.3746,0.0522},{4.3756,0.0544},{4.3766,0.0566},{4.3776,0.0589},{4.3786,0.0612},{4.3796,0.0636},{4.3806,0.066},{4.3816,0.0684},{4.3826,0.0709},{4.3836,0.0734},{4.3846,0.076},{4.3856,0.0786},{4.3866,0.0812},{4.3876,0.0839},{4.3886,0.0867},{4.3896,0.0894},{4.3906,0.0922},{4.3916,0.0951},{4.3926,0.0979},{4.3936,0.1009},{4.3946,0.1038},{4.3956,0.1068},{4.3966,0.1098},{4.3976,0.1129},{4.3986,0.116},{4.3996,0.1191},{4.4006,0.1223},{4.4016,0.1255},{4.4026,0.1288},{4.4036,0.132},{4.4046,0.1353},{4.4056,0.1387},{4.4066,0.142},{4.4076,0.1454},{4.4086,0.1489},{4.4096,0.1523},{4.4106,0.1558},{4.4116,0.1594},{4.4126,0.1629},{4.4136,0.1665},{4.4146,0.1701},{4.4156,0.1738},{4.4166,0.1774},{4.4176,0.1811},{4.4186,0.1848},{4.4196,0.1886},{4.4206,0.1924},{4.4216,0.1962},{4.4226,0.2},{4.4236,0.2038},{4.4246,0.2077},{4.4256,0.2116},{4.4266,0.2155},{4.4276,0.2194},{4.4286,0.2234},{4.4296,0.2274},{4.4306,0.2314},{4.4316,0.2354},{4.4326,0.2394},{4.4336,0.2435},{4.4346,0.2476},{4.4356,0.2517},{4.4366,0.2558},{4.4376,0.2599},{4.4386,0.264},{4.4396,0.2682},{4.4406,0.2724},{4.4416,0.2766},{4.4426,0.2808},{4.4436,0.285},{4.4446,0.2892},{4.4456,0.2934},{4.4466,0.2977},{4.4476,0.302},{4.4486,0.3062},{4.4496,0.3105},{4.4506,0.3148},{4.4516,0.3191},{4.4526,0.3234},{4.4536,0.3278},{4.4546,0.3321},{4.4556,0.3364},{4.4566,0.3408},{4.4576,0.3451},{4.4586,0.3495},{4.4596,0.3538},{4.4606,0.3582},{4.4616,0.3626},{4.4626,0.3669},{4.4636,0.3713},{4.4646,0.3757},{4.4656,0.3801},{4.4666,0.3845},{4.4676,0.3889},{4.4686,0.3933},{4.4696,0.3977},{4.4706,0.402},{4.4716,0.4064},{4.4726,0.4108},{4.4736,0.4152},{4.4746,0.4196},{4.4756,0.424},{4.4766,0.4284},{4.4776,0.4328},{4.4786,0.4372},{4.4796,0.4416},{4.4806,0.4459},{4.4816,0.4503},{4.4826,0.4547},{4.4836,0.459},{4.4846,0.4634},{4.4856,0.4678},{4.4866,0.4721},{4.4876,0.4765},{4.4886,0.4808},{4.4896,0.4851},{4.4906,0.4895},{4.4916,0.4938},{4.4926,0.4981},{4.4936,0.5024},{4.4946,0.5067},{4.4956,0.511},{4.4966,0.5153},{4.4976,0.5196},{4.4986,0.5238},{4.4996,0.5281},{4.5006,0.5323},{4.5016,0.5366},{4.5026,0.5408},{4.5036,0.545},{4.5046,0.5492},{4.5056,0.5534},{4.5066,0.5576},{4.5076,0.5618},{4.5086,0.5659},{4.5096,0.5701},{4.5106,0.5742},{4.5116,0.5783},{4.5126,0.5825},{4.5136,0.5866},{4.5146,0.5906},{4.5156,0.5947},{4.5166,0.5988},{4.5176,0.6028},{4.5186,0.6069},{4.5196,0.6109},{4.5206,0.6149},{4.5216,0.6189},{4.5226,0.6229},{4.5236,0.6269},{4.5246,0.6308},{4.5256,0.6348},{4.5266,0.6387},{4.5276,0.6426},{4.5286,0.6465},{4.5296,0.6504},{4.5306,0.6543},{4.5316,0.6581},{4.5326,0.662},{4.5336,0.6658},{4.5346,0.6696},{4.5356,0.6734},{4.5366,0.6772},{4.5376,0.6809},{4.5386,0.6847},{4.5396,0.6884},{4.5406,0.6921},{4.5416,0.6958},{4.5426,0.6995},{4.5436,0.7032},{4.5446,0.7068},{4.5456,0.7104},{4.5466,0.7141},{4.5476,0.7177},{4.5486,0.7212},{4.5496,0.7248},{4.5506,0.7284},{4.5516,0.7319},{4.5526,0.7354},{4.5536,0.7389},{4.5546,0.7424},{4.5556,0.7459},{4.5566,0.7493},{4.5576,0.7527},{4.5586,0.7562},{4.5596,0.7596},{4.5606,0.7629},{4.5616,0.7663},{4.5626,0.7697},{4.5636,0.773},{4.5646,0.7763},{4.5656,0.7796},{4.5666,0.7829},{4.5676,0.7861},{4.5686,0.7894},{4.5696,0.7926},{4.5706,0.7958},{4.5716,0.799},{4.5726,0.8022},{4.5736,0.8053},{4.5746,0.8085},{4.5756,0.8116},{4.5766,0.8147},{4.5776,0.8178},{4.5786,0.8209},{4.5796,0.8239},{4.5806,0.8269},{4.5816,0.83},{4.5826,0.833},{4.5836,0.8359},{4.5846,0.8389},{4.5856,0.8418},{4.5866,0.8448},{4.5876,0.8477},{4.5886,0.8506},{4.5896,0.8534},{4.5906,0.8563},{4.5916,0.8591},{4.5926,0.8619},{4.5936,0.8647},{4.5946,0.8675},{4.5956,0.8703},{4.5966,0.873},{4.5976,0.8757},{4.5986,0.8784},{4.5996,0.8811},{4.6006,0.8838},{4.6016,0.8864},{4.6026,0.8891},{4.6036,0.8917},{4.6046,0.8943},{4.6056,0.8968},{4.6066,0.8994},{4.6076,0.9019},{4.6086,0.9044},{4.6096,0.9069},{4.6106,0.9094},{4.6116,0.9118},{4.6126,0.9142},{4.6136,0.9166},{4.6146,0.919},{4.6156,0.9214},{4.6166,0.9237},{4.6176,0.926},{4.6186,0.9283},{4.6196,0.9306},{4.6206,0.9328},{4.6216,0.9351},{4.6226,0.9373},{4.6236,0.9394},{4.6246,0.9416},{4.6256,0.9437},{4.6266,0.9458},{4.6276,0.9479},{4.6286,0.95},{4.6296,0.952},{4.6306,0.954},{4.6316,0.9559},{4.6326,0.9579},{4.6336,0.9598},{4.6346,0.9617},{4.6356,0.9635},{4.6366,0.9653},{4.6376,0.9671},{4.6386,0.9689},{4.6396,0.9706},{4.6406,0.9723},{4.6416,0.9739},{4.6426,0.9755},{4.6436,0.9771},{4.6446,0.9787},{4.6456,0.9802},{4.6466,0.9816},{4.6476,0.983},{4.6486,0.9844},{4.6496,0.9857},{4.6506,0.987},{4.6516,0.9883},{4.6526,0.9894},{4.6536,0.9906},{4.6546,0.9917},{4.6556,0.9927},{4.6566,0.9937},{4.6576,0.9946},{4.6586,0.9954},{4.6596,0.9962},{4.6606,0.9969},{4.6616,0.9976},{4.6626,0.9982},{4.6636,0.9987},{4.6646,0.9991},{4.6656,0.9995},{4.6666,0.9997},{4.6676,0.9999},{4.6686,1.},{4.6696,1.},{4.6706,0.9999},{4.6716,0.9997},{4.6726,0.9994},{4.6736,0.9989},{4.6746,0.9984},{4.6756,0.9977},{4.6766,0.9969},{4.6776,0.996},{4.6786,0.9949},{4.6796,0.9936},{4.6806,0.9923},{4.6816,0.9907},{4.6826,0.989},{4.6836,0.9871},{4.6846,0.985},{4.6856,0.9827},{4.6866,0.9802},{4.6876,0.9775},{4.6886,0.9746},{4.6896,0.9714},{4.6906,0.968},{4.6916,0.9643},{4.6926,0.9603},{4.6936,0.956},{4.6946,0.9515},{4.6956,0.9466},{4.6966,0.9413},{4.6976,0.9358},{4.6986,0.9298},{4.6996,0.9235},{4.7006,0.9167},{4.7016,0.9096},{4.7026,0.902},{4.7036,0.8939},{4.7046,0.8853},{4.7056,0.8763},{4.7066,0.8667},{4.7076,0.8565},{4.7086,0.8458}};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your data really does not only resemble a Lorentzian. There are definitely background perturbing functions there.

Adding two terms, one linear and another cubic corrects for a lot though.

Here the code with your model as well as a real, scaled Lorentzian:

```
fit = NonlinearModelFit[data, 
   A*PDF[CauchyDistribution[x0, b], x] + A0 + c*x + 
    d*x^3, {A, {b, 0.1}, {x0, 4.3}, A0, c, d}, x];

fit2 = NonlinearModelFit[data, 
   1 - 1/(1 + eps1^2) + c*x + d*x^3 //. {eps1 -> (x - ws)/a, 
     ws -> 4.3256}, {a, c, d}, x];

Show[{ListPlot[data], 
  Plot[{fit[x], fit2[x]}, {x}~Join~MinMax[data[[All, 1]]], 
   PlotLegends -> {"Scaled Lorentz", "Your model"}]}]
```

> [image: Blockquote]

Comment: Thank you @Julien Kluge, it is really helpful

Comment: I tried to use your code but i find an error in the second model (Fit2) ." General::ivar: 4.003614402142857` is not a valid variable"

Comment: in a fresh notebook everything evaluates fine for me. So did you already define some of the variables? Clear every variable beforehand if not sure.

Comment: okey thank you for your help

Comment: If this anwsers your question, you can mark it as answered if you want.

Comment: @ Julien Kluge Okey I marked it